# Возвращаемое значение от делегата

Tags: c#

В проекте C# я использую делегаты для вызова методов из библиотеки C++, загруженную в процесс.Использую данный код:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal delegate void Generation();
internal static Generation GenerationInvoker;

CreateDelegate < Generation > ("TestExample")

internal T CreateDelegate < T > (string procName) where T: class {
    var procAddress = GetProcAddress(procName);

    if (procAddress != IntPtr.Zero) {
        return (T)(object) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(procAddress, typeof(T));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Метод успешно вызывается, но могу ли я вернуть ответ из вызываемого метода?Допустим вернуть числовое значение с "плавающей" запятой (float).

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо всего лишь исправить тип возврата делегата:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal delegate void Generation();
```

переписать на

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal delegate float Generation();
```

Comment: Большое Спасибо!